# Converting POST values to conform to different convention

Tags: php, database-design, naming-conventions

Title is kinda confusing, sorry.

I'm collecting a bunch of data on my website that I will eventually be sending over to another website's API via `cURL`. I can make everything work on the technical side of things, but the biggest trouble I'm having is with semantics.

I'm not a fan [at all] of the naming conventions the other website uses for its `POST` values [and, presumably, its DB structure.]

**My Site**

```
book-title => Book of Thieves
bind-type => wire //enum value
shipping-address-1 => 123 Chesterfield Road
shipping-address-2 => Apt. 204
```

**Remote Site**

```
Title => Book of Thieves
BindType => wire-bind //enum value
Shipping1 => 123 Chesterfield Road 
Shipping2 => Apt. 204
```

My question is: What is the best way to utilize my own preferred data structure internally, but when it comes time to `POST` it to the Remote Site's API, convert the data to the conventions that they have implemented? This includes not only the keys, but the values as well (some values are predefined and not user input.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a pattern perspective, I would consider encapsulating into a class that takes full responsibility for interaction with your remote site (with no other responsibilities).  There's a variety of patterns that are in that realm--Delegate, Facade, Presenter--but the basic logic would be the same.

So you could create a TheirBook class that wraps YourBook and returns the methods in the form that their site requires.

Or you could create a PostToTheirSite class that takes YourBook but directly generates the POST request using thier semantics.

In either case you're generating one dedicated peice of code that is responsible only for semantic translation and not any other form of business logic.